# Javascript (and angular) , if/else to determine variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am prepping data for sending to the server and I would like to check a an input model to determine a variable. So I have an input like so -

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkYes">
```

And I'm tryig to store a variable like

```
  var isYes = checkYes : true ? false;
```

So the desired result is, if checkYes is check, set isYes to true, else false.

I know this is pretty simple javascript, but I think I have it wrong and could use some help. It would be GREAT if someone could explain how these things work, or point me to an article o something that does, because I'm not even sure what they are called.

Comment: You just have the ternary reversed, it should be: `var isYes = checkYes ? true : false;`

Comment: @DavinTryon Thank you! I know this is pretty low level javascript, but I learned it completely backwards.

Comment: In my answer, I included a link the documentation.  Have a read of that for further detail. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called a `ternary` operator ([documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)).

In your case, you just have the `?` and the `:` in the wrong order.  It should be:

```
var isYes = checkYes ? true : false;
```